# Better/colour-coded visualization in TFS Annotate in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'd like to see something in TFS's Annotate mode (in Visual Studio 2012) that gives me more of an idea of how the code came together.

I've included an image below of how it might be put together, with individual colour codes for each changeset, but it'd be nice to see if the change was an add or an edit, etc.

Are there any plugins out there that spring to anyone's minds?

[image: Crappy comparision]